# checkbox get disabled in ng-repeat of accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, checkbox

I have build a list of accordions, each accordion represent a group of items.
I have used ng-repeat to iterate through group names,each group has a checkbox which indicate if it is chosen or not.

The example works fine for single group of accordion, but the moment I am putting the accordion inside ng-repeat, the checkbox can't be selected at all.

Here is the code, the main checkbox of each group title doesn't work apparently, I am try to figure out the reason for this.

My main Question is:

1.How can I make the checkboxes of Group1 and Group2 and Group3 active,so I can select them properly, In current situation, I can't select the checkboxes at all(of Group1,Group2 and Group3).

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainCTRL',function($scope){
  $('.collapse').collapse();
  $scope.title="Hello World";
  $scope.items1 = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']
})
```

```css
.ui-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.ui-checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.ui-checkbox + label:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  /**#fff*/
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  color: #99a1a7;
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  color: #1279C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
<div ng-repeat="item in items1">
    <div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion-{{$index}}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{$index}}"
                       data-target="#collapseOne-{{$index}}">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk1-{{$index}}" value="">
                        <label for="chk1-{{$index}}">{{item}}</label>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne-{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="driving-license-kind">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1">A</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2">B</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3">C</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4">D</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5">E</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use [angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) for your accordion ?
With it you can do something like this :
 `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); toggleOpen();"` on your input type checkbox.

Comment: I don't use bootstrap ui, also you can see in this example that I don;t use bootstrap UI library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is because your checkboxes are nested inside anchors. Simply change:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{$index}}"
                       data-target="#collapseOne-{{$index}}">
```

To:

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{$index}}"
                       data-target="#collapseOne-{{$index}}">
```

**See working example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainCTRL',function($scope){
  $('.collapse').collapse();
  $scope.title="Hello World";
  $scope.items1 = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']
})
```

```css
.ui-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.ui-checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.ui-checkbox + label:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  /**#fff*/
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  color: #99a1a7;
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  color: #1279C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
<div ng-repeat="item in items1">
    <div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion-{{$index}}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{$index}}"
                       data-target="#collapseOne-{{$index}}">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk1-{{$index}}" value="">
                        <label for="chk1-{{$index}}">{{item}}</label>
                    </div>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne-{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="driving-license-kind">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1">A</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2">B</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3">C</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4">D</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5">E</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the ids you assigned. Make the ids unique, and the checkbox starts working. Here is the fixed snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainCTRL',function($scope){
  $('.collapse').collapse();
  $scope.title="Hello World";
  $scope.items1 = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']
})
```

```css
.ui-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.ui-checkbox + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.ui-checkbox + label:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  /**#fff*/
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #1279C6;
  color: #99a1a7;
}
.ui-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  color: #1279C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
<div ng-repeat="item in items1">
    <div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion-{{$index}}">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{$index}}"
                       data-target="#collapseOne-{{$index}}">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk1-{{$index}}" value="">
                        <label for="chk1-{{$index}}">{{item}}</label>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne-{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="driving-license-kind">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-1">A</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-2">B</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-3">C</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-4">D</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="ui-checkbox" id="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5" value="">
                            <label for="chk2-cb-{{item}}-5">E</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: still the checkboxes in your example doesn't work, I mean the checkboxes Group1,Group2 and Group3. I need these checkboxes to work properly.